# Delete postmeta when uninstall/delete plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, post-meta

I have a custom plugin I created that adds some custom meta input fields to every post

I want to remove all this plugin generated rows of postmeta for each post when I uninstall/delete the plugin

what code should I add to the plugin php file to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [`register_uninstall_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/). There is as well a [`register_deactivation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) function which can be usefull as well.

You could use them for calling a function which will remove the data from DB. But you should be careful and maybe let user check a checkbox to do so.